# Why are these form fields not lined up in Production but are perfect in development

Tags: css, html, heroku

I have created a modal form.  In development mode it looks great as follows:

[image]

However in production mode on Heroku it looks as follows:

[image]

I've been looking at this over and over and changing values such as the width of the boxes etc and nothing seems to be working. Any help appreciated to get the form in production mode to match the design in development mode.

The HTML for the MODAL:

```
<div id="openModal" class="formModalContainer">
    <div class="topBox">
        <div class="closeModal"><a href="#">X</a></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="formLogo"><%= image_tag "ProvenWordLogoSmall.png", :alt=> "Samll Version of ProvenWord Logo" %></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottomBox">
        <h3>Free Quote Form</h3>
        <div class="formContainer">
            <form class="freeQuoteForm"  autocomplete="off">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="formField">
                        <label class="formLabel" for="firstName">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="firstName" class="input" tabindex="1" required>
                    </div> <!-- holds the first name field -->
                    <div class="formField rightField">
                        <label class="formLabel" for="LastName">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="LastName" class="input" tabindex="2" required>
                    </div> <!-- holds the last name field -->
                    <div class="formField wide">
                        <label class="formLabel" for="email">Email Address</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" class="input" tabindex="3" required>
                    </div> <!-- holds the email field -->
                    <div class="formField wide sampleText">
                        <label class="formLabel sampleText" for="sampleText">Please include a 1000 word sample from your document.</label>
                        <textarea rows="12" cols="50" id="sampleText" tabindex="4" wrap="hard" class="input" required></textarea>
                    </div> <!-- holds the sample text field -->
                    <div class="formField">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="input checkbox" name="verifyResources" id="verifyResources" tabindex='5' value="verify" required>
                        <label class="formLabel checkbox" for="verifyResources">Check resource formatting?</label>
                    </div> <!-- holds the checkbox -->
                    <div class="formField rightField">
                        <select name="selectStyle" class="input selectStyle" tabindex="6" required>
                            <option selected disabled>Choose Editing Standard</option>
                            <option value="APA">APA</option>
                            <option value="EPA">EPA</option>
                        </select>
                    </div> <!-- holds the select box -->
                    <p class="disclaimer"><%=image_tag "lock.png", :alt=> 'icon of a padlock'%>We respect your privacy. Your information will be kept strictly confidential.</p>
                    <input class="btn-style" type="submit" value="Submit">
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div><!-- formContainer -->
        <div class="infoBox" id="sampleTextBox">
            <div class="popupPointer pointerRight">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias dignissimos sapiente non illum nesciunt! Quae quisquam, maiores autem. Tempora minima fuga molestias, error corrupti, nulla repellat delectus totam quae quod!</p> 
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="closeInfoBox">I understand</a>
            </div><!-- popupPointer -->
        </div><!-- infoBox -->
        <div class="infoBox" id="verifyResourcesBox">
            <div class="popupPointer pointerRight">
                <p>CHeck this shit</p> 
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="closeInfoBox">I understand</a>
            </div><!-- popupPointer -->
        </div><!-- infoBox -->
    </div><!-- Bottom Box -->
</div><!-- modalDialog -->
```

The CSS:

.formModalContainer {

```
    /* The fixed postion ensures that the modal will be there as the user scrolls down the page */
    position: fixed;
    font-family: "Sinkin Sans", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    /* setting these to 0 makes sure */
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    /* The backgrond here is dark and almost completly opaque */
    background-image: url(asset-path('paper2.png'));
    background-repeat: repeat;
    /* This makes usre that the modal is above all other content */
    z-index: 99998;
    opacity:0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
}

.formModalContainer.open {
    animation: fadeIn 0.5s forwards;
    /* This means that when the link is hovered over it becomes active  */
    pointer-events: auto;
}



.formModalContainer.closed {
    animation: fadeOut 1s ease forwards;
    /* This means that when the link is hovered over it becomes active  */
    /*pointer-events: none;*/
}


.topBox {
    width: 640px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 45px;
    position: relative;
}

.closeModal {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    color: gray;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    width: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px;
    float: right;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

.closeModal:hover {
    background-color: #92E7C9;
}

.closeModal a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.formLogo {
position: absolute;
top: -30px;
}

.bottomBox {
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    margin: 30px auto;
    width: 640px;
    height: 680px;
    border: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
}

.formModalContainer.open > .topBox > .formLogo {
    animation: fadeIn 1.5s  forwards, slideDown 0.5s 0.5s forwards;
}

.formModalContainer.open > .bottomBox  {
    animation: fadeIn 1.5s forwards, slideUpBottom 0.75s forwards;
}

.formModalContainer.closed > .topBox > .formLogo {
    animation: slideUp 0.5s ease forwards;
}

.formModalContainer.closed > .bottomBox {
    animation: slideDownBottom 0.75s forwards;
}

.formModalContainer.open > .topBox > .closeModal {
    animation: fadeIn 2.5s forwards, bounceInUp 1s forwards;
}

.bottomBox h3 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;

}

.formContainer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 530px;
    height: 531px;
    text-align: right;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

.formField {
    font-family: "Sinkin Sans", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 200;
    width: 50%;
    height: 60px;
    border: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
    border-bottom: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    animation: fadeColorWhite 0.5s 0s ease 1 forwards;
}

.formField.wide {
    width: 100%;
}

.rightField {
    float: right;
    border-left: none;
}


.input {
    font-family: "Sinkin Sans", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 300;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    text-indent: 10px;
    outline:none;
    margin: 0;

}

.formLabel {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 2px;
    color: #bfbfbf;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center left;
}

.formField.selected {
    animation: fadeColorBlue 0.5s forwards;
}

.formField:hover {
    animation: fadeColorBlue 0.5s forwards; 
}

.formLabel.selected {
    animation: colorScaleMove 0.75s forwards;
}

.sampleText {
    height:350px;
}

#sampleText {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    resize: none;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.formLabel.sampleText {
    top: 5px;
    height: 20px;
}

.formLabel.sampleText.selected {
    animation: fadeOut 0.5s forwards;
}

.input.checkbox {
    margin-left: 7px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.formLabel.checkbox {
    top: 20px;
    left: 30px;
    transition: color 1s;
}

.formLabel.checkbox.selected {
    animation: none;
    color: black;
}


p.disclaimer {
    padding: 10px 0 15px 0;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
}

p img {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

.btn-style{
    border : solid 0px #e6e6e6;
    border-radius : 2px;
    moz-border-radius : 2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow : 0px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,1.0);
    -moz-box-shadow : 0px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,1.0);
    box-shadow : 0px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,1.0);
    font-size : 15px;
    color : #000000;
    padding : 5px 19px;
    background-color : #92E7C9;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}


input.btn-style:hover {
    background-color: #A5FDDE;
}

legend {
  padding: 0;
  display: table;
}
fieldset {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0.01em 0 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 0;
}
body:not(:-moz-handler-blocked) fieldset {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Most likely scenario is that something is different between the two environments. Maybe a javascript or stylesheet exists on one but not the other (maybe by design or maybe it's been referenced incorrectly and isn't loading) and this is having some kind of unintentional effect on your modal.

Comment: Check the JS console in your browser for errors.

Comment: I've done more investigating. No JS errors. However, if I open a new tab and load the website in that tab and then open the  modal,  the form is perfect. If I then reload the website and open the modal the form is as I have shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say exactly why this was happening but I can give an update as to how I fixed it. I upgraded my version of Chrome.  I also tested my site in Safari and Firefox. There are small glitches to fix as is normal for different browsers but the form layout is correct.